# Getting Invalid Coupon messages on order placed - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, coupon, onestepcheckout

I am getting that following messages[image: Your Coupon was successfully removed]
[image: Current Customer does not have an active cart.] on placing the order.

Any Help will be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: So once after getting this message have you checked your cart to see if the product still exists in the cart

Comment: @RajMohanR The order has been placed.

Comment: you are getting this error when clicking place order right

Comment: Yeap. I am getting on Placing the order

Comment: I can able to see you are using One Step Checkout. Can you please confirm if this error does occur in default Magento One Page Checkout too